# Use aggregate function to calculate output in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I've been trying myself and searching for a while now over the net and stackoverflow to no success. I've got a dataframe which I subset from applying conditions and select for projection but fail to retrieve aggregated output.

Dataframe `mydf`:

```
mydf = list()
mydf = cbind(mydf, 
            c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco"),
            c(4000, 7600, 2500),
            c("Bartosz", "Damian", "Maciej"))
mydf = as.data.frame(mydf)
colnames(mydf) = c("city","salary","name")
```

Let's assume given part of dataframe returned with:

```
subset(mydf, city == "New York", select = c(salary, name))
```

which return a data frame such as:

```
   salary    name
9    4000 Bartosz
10   7600  Damian
```

Now I need to calculate from the given salary a `sum`, `avg` and choose an employee with least salary from above data frame, preferably using one-liner by modifying the above code (I'm guessing it's possible), so that it returns:

for `sum`: 11600

for `avg`: 5800

for least: 4000 Bartosz

---

I've tried things as (1)

```
subset(mydf, city == "New York", select = sum(salary))
```

or (2)

```
x = subset(mydf, city == "New York", select = salary)
min(x)
```

and many more combination which only yields errors saying that summary function is only defined on a data frame with all variables being numbers (2) or the same output as the first code without `sum` (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that your dataframe object actually contains a bunch of lists.  So if you take

```
ny.df = subset(mydf, city == "New York", select = c(salary, name))
```

then any of the subsequent work needs to be peppered with `as.numeric` calls to translate your lists into vectors.  These will give you your answers:

```
sum(as.numeric(ny.df$salary)) # sum
mean(as.numeric(ny.df$salary)) # avg
ny.df[which(as.numeric(ny.df$salary) == min(as.numeric(ny.df$salary))),] # row with min salary
```

**Alternatively,** you can define `mydf` as a dataframe of vectors instead of a dataframe of lists:

```
mydf = data.frame(c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco"),
              c(4000, 7600, 2500),
              c("Bartosz", "Damian", "Maciej"))
colnames(mydf) = c("city","salary","name")

ny.df = subset(mydf, city == "New York", select = c(salary, name))
sum(ny.df$salary)
mean(ny.df$salary)
ny.df[which(ny.df$salary == min(ny.df$salary)),]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why using list in this case to construct a data frame is a bad choice. I've decided to redecline my dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mydf` was weird so I made my own. I split `mydf` by `city` and then obtained the necessary data from running necessary operations (mean, sum, etc.) on each subgroup.

```
#DATA
mydf = structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("New York", 
"San Francisco"), class = "factor"), salary = c(4000, 7600, 2500
), name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Bartosz", "Damian", "Maciej"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("city", "salary", "name"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(mydf, mydf$city), function(a)
    data.frame(employee = a$name[which.min(a$salary)], #employee with least salary
               mean = mean(a$salary), #mean salary
               sum = sum(a$salary)))) #sum of salary
#              employee mean   sum
#New York       Bartosz 5800 11600
#San Francisco   Maciej 2500  2500
```

Comment: For starters, thanks a lot for putting your effort. I may have provided misleading information. I need separate queries to calculate sum, mean and choose the least. Three separate calls. As for sum for example: only the summed salary as output. Is that better explained?

Comment: You're exactly right, though, it seems pretty complicated compared with what I've come up with after @lebelinoz answer. I didn't know how my `mydf` was weird. +1 for the effort anyways though, thanks

Comment: And your help is much appreciated. If you felt otherwise I apologize, didn't mean that. I'll definitely use this approach when in need.

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame is structured unusally as lists within the dataframe, which may be casuign you issues.  Here is a dplyr solution (now edited to find th elowest salary)

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data.frame(
             city = c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco"),
             salary = c(4000, 7600, 2500),
             name = c("Bartosz", "Damian", "Maciej"))

mydf %>% 
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(salary),
         sum = sum(salary)) %>%
  top_n(-1, wt = salary) 

#            city salary    name   avg   sum
#          <fctr>  <dbl>  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      New York   4000 Bartosz  5800 11600
# 2 San Francisco   2500  Maciej  2500  2500
```

Comment: For starters, thanks a lot for putting your effort. I may have provided misleading information. I need separate queries to calculate sum, mean and choose the least. Three separate calls. As for sum for example: only the summed salary as output. Is that better explained?

Answer (score 1):

I think the dplyr is what you might be looking for:

```
   library(dplyr)
   mydf %>% 
   group_by(city) %>% 
   filter (city =="New York") %>%
   summarise(mean(salary), sum(salary))

  # A tibble: 1 x 3
  #  city mean(salary) sum(salary)
  #  <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
  #1 New York         5800       11600
```

There is a good tutorial at this link link[https://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial]

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and fast solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) 

setDT(mydf)[, .( salary_sum = sum(salary),
                 salary_avg = mean(salary),
                 name = name[which.min(salary)]), by= city]

>             city salary_sum salary_avg    name
> 1:      New York      11600       5800 Bartosz
> 2: San Francisco       2500       2500  Maciej
```

your dataset:

```
mydf = data.frame(city=c("New York", "New York", "San Francisco"),
                  salary=c(4000, 7600, 2500),
                  name=c("Bartosz", "Damian", "Maciej"))
```